# How to add string to array type column in iOS parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, parse-platform

I have defined a column on the cloud as an array type. For first time adding value to this array I tried:

```
//Code for OK button
NSLog(@"Add=== %@",self.friendObj);
PFQuery *query =  [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.friendObj block:^(PFObject *newFriend, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Added");
    [newFriend addObject:@"flying" forKey:@"friendList"]; 
}];
NSLog(@"End of query");
```

output is:

```
2015-09-11 10:17:40.318 evend[2125:405698] button11
2015-09-11 10:17:41.551 evend[2125:405698] Add=== X74jDXLaHF
2015-09-11 10:17:41.552 evend[2125:405698] End of query
2015-09-11 10:17:41.924 evend[2125:405698] Added
```

As you can see it goes through query and `self.friendObj` is not null but nothing added on backend. I also tried this

```
[newFriend addObject:@[@"flying"] forKey:@"friendList"];
```

But still it did not work!

Comment: Have you init the "newFriend" using some code snippet like NSMutableArray *newFriend = [NSMutableArray array]; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the newFriend object after updating it.

```
[newFriend saveInBackground];
```